# File list error on load Android ListActivity

Tags: android, file, list, directory

I got this error, and i dont know who is the problem. In some devices work de app but in other make this error.

//THIS IS THE CODE

```
package com.neoadn.takerenamephoto;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListaFotos extends ListActivity {

private File file, temp_file;
private List<String> myList;
String root_sd;
File imagen;
String direccionFile;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondo_p);

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

    root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File( root_sd + "/Pictures/TRPHOTO" ) ;       
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));
```

The line 41 is:

```
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
```

This shows a listactivity of files and folders into some folders.

**UPDATED:**

Finally i used this to fix the problem: ( if list is not null, then load. If is null not load)

```
    if(list != null) {
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++) {
        // do your for loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you even know when is the error coming..?

Comment: Post your code and check the line : com.neoadn.takerenamephoto.ListaFotos.onCreate(ListaFotos.java:41)

Comment: it says right there in your log that you have a NullPointerException at Line 41 in your ListaFotos class. In Eclipse you can even double-click on that line and it will lead you straight to the problematic line

Comment: Updated. line 41 is :     for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)

Comment: why are'nt you checking if external storage is present, or mounted !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens when the following statement returns null:

```
File list[] = file.listFiles();
```

That can happen when your directory "file" doens't contain any files. Because your list **list** is therefore null, the following statement

```
for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
```

crashes with a NullPointerException. I'd recommend you to check if your list variable is null before entering the for loop like this:

```
if(list != null) {
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++) {
        // do your for loop
    }
}
```